# Cross-posting an answer between AskUbuntu and SuperUser

Tags: discussion, answers

While looking for a way to activate an X window from the command line, I found two particularly relevant results. One on AskUbuntu and the other on SuperUser.

The answers given in both questions didn't really work for my particular use case, so I posted my own solution on *both sites*. According to [meta stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301533/229922), crossposting answers shouldn't really be an issue. But I wanted to be sure it was really the case here.

Here are the corresponding links to both answers:

- https://superuser.com/a/1513454/224101
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1199542/621782

Comment: Each answer should be independent of one another.  This means you should not link to answer here at Super User within an answer to a question asked on Ask Ubuntu.  Additionally, you should only avoid submitting the same answer, to multiple questions within the same community multiple times.

Comment: _you should only avoid submitting the same answer, to multiple questions within the same community multiple times_ Of course ;) However: _Each answer should be independent of one another. This means you should not link to answer here at Super User within an answer to a question asked on Ask Ubuntu._ Could you elaborate on that part? Do you just mean each answer should be self-contained--or do you think I shouldn't mention the other website at all, even if it may provide alternate answers?

Comment: If you an answer a question here at Super User and submit an answer, it should be an answer to the question here at Super User, not a question on some other community.  If you are quoting the existence of an answer written by somebody else, you should cite and quote the answer obviously, my initial suggestion was with regards to answer(s) written by the same author.